# trying to run Xamarin Android app results in "Could not access the Package Manager"

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device

I decided to give Xamarin a try.  So I followed the various articles at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/ to install Xamarin, then build an Android app.  That was pretty easy, especially since I already have Visual Studio 2017 installed.  The code compiled fine.  I set up an Android Virtual Device and tried to debug/run the app in that AVD.  Everything I've tried results in:

```
Build succeeded.
Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

Deploy failed on ...[AVD device here]
```

I have VS 2017 running on Windows 10.

The development experience was encouraging, since I've been using VS/C# for such a long time now, but getting past this emulator issue has, so far, been a complete roadblock.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?

Are you using `ARM` based emulator ? They are extremely slow and take lots of time to boot up. As [Anubhav Ranjan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545360/xamarin-deploying-not-working-with-android) said, just wait until emulator be loaded completely, once it finished it should work.

Try using an `x86` based emulator, and use  the [Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/1-hardware-acceleration/). Those run much faster, still a little on the slow side, but bearable.